# why is this lein new template is failing

Tags: clojure, leiningen, luminus

I just started with clojure web development, but, got stuck on step 1.

```
D:\cloj\work>lein new luminus guestbook +h2
Could not find artifact luminus:lein-template:jar:? in central    
(https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
Could not find artifact luminus:lein-template:jar:? in clojars 
(https://clojars.org/repo/)
This could be due to a typo in :dependencies or network issues.
If you are behind a proxy, try setting the 'http_proxy' environment variable.
```

1. I can see the template in clojars at 
   https://clojars.org/repo/luminus/lein-template/
2. I am not behind a proxy.
3. my .lein/profiles.clj has the following content

   {:user
     {
     :java-cmd "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe"
     :plugins [
           [lein-ancient "0.6.10"]
           [luminus/lein-template ​"2.9.10.74"​]
       ]
      }
    }

what am I missing !
thank you

Comment: hm, it works on my pc (linux) - AND I do not have a plugins entry in `.lein/profiles.clj` for `luminus/lein-template`, try removing it

Comment: thanks. I removed and it worked.

Comment: One of you guys should add it as an answer to be accepted. Help ones who come here from google with the same problem

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue when reading the Web development With Clojure ebook. The problem was that I copy pasted the `profiles.clj` configuration from the ebook, which resulted in some invisible characters getting included that messed up the configuration. I verified this with a hex viewer.

The solution is to type the configuration manually or copy paste from here if you're lazy :)

```
{:user 
    {:plugins [
            [luminus/lein-template "2.9.10.74"]
        ]
    }
}
```

Of course you can just omit this too, but then you'll be using the latest version which might have some changes from when the book was written.